# How to merge and push a local branch in git

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-push, git-pull

Hi I am in difficulty with this scenarios:
I have two local branch: **develop** and **branch1**.  On remote I have **develop** branch only.

The steps that i followed:

- I have pulled remote develop from my local develop.
- I have created new branch **branch1** and add some code inside it.

I need to create, and push all the modification of **branch1** on remote.
After doing it I am costrained to go to github and make a pull request from my "branch1" remote branch to the develop remote branch.

Which are the steps that I need to do in case of conflicts?
I try to read a lot but the major part are merging in local and push on develop ( or master ) but my scenario is different cause i need to push on remote **branch1** and from there to ask to review the code from a person and make a pull request. I need to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question:

- You are following a standard pull request workflow that merges feature branches ("branch1") into a long-lived "develop" branch.
- Sometimes, as a result of the peer review process, you end up with merge conflicts. You want to avoid this.

Solution:

**Avoiding merge conflicts:**

There is no way to "avoid" merge conflicts in a workflow such as this one (or in any workflow, really). The best you can do is to remind the peer reviewer that time-consuming merge conflicts are likely to occur unless they are reviewed and merged quickly.

**Resolving merge conflicts:**

Most of the time, resolving the merge conflicts in this workflow is easy:

- In your local copy, checkout develop:

```
git pull origin develop
```

- Rebase "branch1" against develop:

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase develop
```

- Interactively resolve the merge conflicts.

You really do need to know how to resolve merge conflicts, e.g. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/3787051).

- Push branch1:

```
git push origin branch1 --force
```

(Force is required because the rebase operation rewrites the history.)